# .x86 file not executing

Tags: executable

I've tracked down a game named [superhot](http://superhotgame.com/) and downloaded zipped Linux version. I unzipped it and there was a directory named SUPERHOT-LINUX_Data and file with extension .x86. I went to properties and ticked "can execute". But the file still doesn't start. All i can see is bunch of processes starting upon clicking on that file. Their names starts with unity.

Should i install some libraries or something?

Thanks for advice

Edit: I've tried as damien said and mono installed successfully, but still nothing. Then i tried running that file from terminal:

```
$ ./SUPERHOT-LINUX.x86
```

and it returned:

```
./SUPERHOT-LINUX.x86: error while loading shared libraries: libGLU.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I guess something is missing?

Comment: I downloaded the zip file and had a look in the superhot-linux-data directory and it appears you need mono. Try `sudo apt-get install mono-runtime` then repeat what you tried and report the results to your question

Comment: @tiwy have you solved your problem?

Comment: well actually i downgraded my linux to 12.04. And it worked. But on  13.04 none of suggestions worked.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I solved by installing these libraries:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libglu1-mesa:i386 libxcursor1:i386
```

You can print shared library dependencies with:

```
$ ldd SUPERHOT-LINUX.x86
```

Comment: the ":i386" makes the difference..

Comment: You can improve your answer by explaining why, as @Tapper said, is `i386` part important.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, your system lacks that library (`libGLU`). In this case it is available in the repositories so you just need to run

```
$ sudo apt-get install libglu1-mesa
```

If you find similar errors you can try to find the needed package using `apt-file`. In this case, to search packages that have the file `libGLU.so.1`:

```
$ apt-file search libGLU.so.1
libglu1-mesa: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLU.so.1
libglu1-mesa: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLU.so.1.3.08000
libglu1-mesa: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLU.so.1.3.08004
```