# Superhot won't run

Tags: games

I've downloaded a prototype of a game called superhot [here](http://superhotgame.com/). I've extracted it, and downloaded the plugins mentioned in a similar question [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/348267/x86-file-not-executing), but no joy. When i click on the .x86 file, I get

"SUPERHOT September 2013.x86
Could not display 'SUPERHOT September 2013.x86'
Reason: Unrecognised or unsupported data."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the file is downloaded and extracted into your ~/Downloads folder, run the following commands in an open terminal to run the game:

```
cd ~/Downloads/SUPERHOT_Prototype_Linux/Linux
chmod +x *x86
$HOME/Downloads/SUPERHOT_Prototype_Linux/Linux/*.x86
```

If you need to, start over and run the following commands in an open terminal one by one to download:

```
wget http://superhotgame-new.azurewebsites.net/BUILDS/SUPERHOT_Prototype_Linux.zip
unzip SUPERHOT_Prototype_Linux.zip
cd Linux
chmod +x $HOME/Linux/*.x86
```

Finally, execute the following command to run the game:

```
$HOME/SUPERHOT_Prototype_Linux/Linux/*.x86
```

[image]

It should now run just fine.
If it doesn't run, please post the exact output from the terminal to show us why so we can help, thanks.

Comment: you may need to install wine and/or wine-compholio etc ... like wine-staging