# I ve downloaded Super Hot (for linux) at the official site, but i dont know how to run it

Tags: downloads

Heres the link:

[LINK REMOVED]

Please let me know if you know how to run it.

Comment: Random link on random website on free site hosting site is suspicious...

Comment: See also, http://askubuntu.com/questions/348267/x86-file-not-executing

Answer (score 0):

Run the following commands to run superhot.

First, make a build directory and download superhot to that directory:

```
mkdir SUPERHOT;cd SUPERHOT
wget http://superhotgame-new.azurewebsites.net/BUILDS/SUPERHOT_Prototype_Linux.zip
```

Unzip the file:

```
unzip *
```

Change directories:

```
cd Linux
```

Now, make the file executable:

```
chmod +x "SUPERHOT September 2013.x86"
```

Finally, make an alias for superhot so that you can run the game using a simple command (we escape the spaces in the alias):

```
echo 'alias SUPERHOT="$HOME/SUPERHOT/Linux/SUPERHOT\ September\ 2013.x86"' | tee -a ~/.bashrc; . ~/.bashrc
```

Now, run the following command to play the game:

```
SUPERHOT &
```

or

```
SUPERHOT
```

Please post any errors, thanks!